# Xcode 11.2.1 confused about the minimum deployment target

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xcode11, deployment-target

I have a library and an app in the same workspace. One is dependent on the other. When I compile I get an error saying that the library is build for iOS 11 but the apps deployment target is iOS 10.
I change the minimum deployment target for the library. Same error.
I change the minimum deployment target for the app. Same error.
I clean the build folder, delete the derived data, reboot the computer. Same error.
The minimum deployment target can be changed in two places in the project settings, either in the info tab or the build settings tab. They both seem to be in sync.
Is there anywhere else it is stored?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I fixed it. Right click on your project file (something.xcodeproj), select 'Show Package Contents'. Open project.pbxproj with a text editor and search for IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET. There will be 4 hits, 2 for Release mode and 2 for Debug mode. One of the Release mode values and one of the Debug mode values will be wrong. Hand edit them to the correct values. After this I checked my other projects. Every single one has inconsistent values for the minimum deployment target. I have a feeling that this is a problem with xcode 11.2.1 as this is the first time I have had this problem, but I am not sure. Has anyone else had this problem?